# I am getting a PSQLException; column name brandid was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, single-page-application, jpql

I am creating custom Repository methods to find a brand by name and get a list of brands by type. To prevent deleting and creating brands that already exist there are existsByName methods. The issue is with mapping the request. Here is my code:

Model layer:

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "brandid")
    private long brandID;

    @Column(name = "brand_name" ,nullable = false)
    private String brandName;

    @Column(name = "brand_type",nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private BrandType brandType;

    public Brand() {
    }

    public Brand(long brandID, String brandName, BrandType brandType) {
        this.brandID = brandID;
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.brandType = brandType;
    }

    public long getBrandID() {
        return brandID;
    }
    public void setBrandID(long brandID) {
        this.brandID = brandID;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }
    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    public BrandType getBrandType() {
        return brandType;
    }
    public void setBrandType(BrandType brandType) {
        this.brandType = brandType;
    }
}
```

Repository Layer:

```
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE brand_name=:brandName", nativeQuery = true)
    Brand getBrandByName(@Param("brandName") String brandName);

    //    Creating exists by methods so we can only delete brands if they exist (Check service)
    @Query(value="SELECT COUNT(brand_name) > 0 from brand WHERE brand_name=:brandName", nativeQuery = true)
    boolean existsByName(@Param("brandName")String brandName);

    @Query(value="DELETE FROM brand WHERE brand_name=:brandName", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteBrand(@Param("brandName") String brandName);

    //    Creating exists by methods so we get brands by type if type exists (Check service)
    @Query(value="SELECT COUNT(brand_type) > 0 from brand WHERE brand_type=:brandType", nativeQuery = true)
    boolean existsByType(@Param("brandType") BrandType brandType);

    @Query(value="SELECT brand_name, brand_type FROM brand WHERE brand_type=:brandType", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Brand> getBrandsByType(@Param("brandType") BrandType brandType);
}
```

Service layer:

```
 public interface BrandService {
    List<Brand> getBrands();

    boolean existsByType(BrandType brandType);
    List<Brand> getBrandsByType(BrandType brandType);

    boolean existsByName(String brandName);
    Brand getBrandByName(String brandName);
    void deleteBrand(String brandName);
    long addBrand(Brand brand);
}
```

Service Implementation layer

```
@Service
public class BrandServiceImpl implements BrandService {

    @Autowired
    BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Brand> getBrands() {
        return brandRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsByType(BrandType brandType) {
        return brandRepository.existsByType(brandType);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Brand> getBrandsByType(BrandType brandType) {
        if (brandRepository.existsByType(brandType)) {
            return brandRepository.getBrandsByType(brandType);
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsByName(String brandName) {
        return brandRepository.existsByName(brandName);
    }

    @Override
    public Brand getBrandByName(String brandName) {
        if (brandRepository.existsByName(brandName)) {
            return brandRepository.getBrandByName(brandName);
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBrand(String brandName) {
        brandRepository.deleteBrand(brandName);
    }

    @Override
    public long addBrand(Brand brand) {
        Brand newBrand = brandRepository.save(brand);
        return newBrand.getBrandID();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/brands")
public class BrandController {

    @Autowired
    private BrandService brandService;

    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getBrands() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(brandService.getBrands());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/name/{brandname}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getBrandByName(@PathVariable("brandname") String brandName) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(brandService.getBrandByName(brandName));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/type/{brandType}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getBrandsByType(@PathVariable("brandType") BrandType brandType) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(brandService.getBrandsByType(brandType));
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/name/{brandname}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteBrand(@PathVariable("brandname") String brandName) {
        brandService.deleteBrand(brandName);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addBrand(@RequestBody Brand brand) {
        long newId = brandService.addBrand(brand);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(newId).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(location);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
2021-04-22 14:55:39.527  WARN 11346 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2021-04-22 14:55:39.528 ERROR 11346 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name brandid was not found in this ResultSet.
2021-04-22 14:55:39.544 ERROR 11346 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE brand_name=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name brandid was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2748) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2631) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:803) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1172) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.getBrandByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at nl.marijnploeg.kitereparatie.service.BrandServiceImpl.getBrandByName(BrandServiceImpl.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at nl.marijnploeg.kitereparatie.controller.BrandController.getBrandByName(BrandController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Remove the `@Query`, Spring Data JPA will already support that out-of-the-box, no need to write your own queries. Also instead of using exists, a better way is to create a `findBy` method which returns an `Optional` and use that, that way you only have 1 query to issue instead of 2.

Comment: Check your actual database and see what the brandid column was actually named. I've had Spring do some weird stuff with naming even when using the @Column annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the suggestion. Removing `@Query` and `@Param` causes bean errors. This is my first spring project so it is a little unclear which method to use for creating custom methods. Thought that using `@Query` was the solution...?

Comment: you the properties need to match the attribute name so `existsByBrandType` or `findByBrandType` or `findByBrandName` the latter can return an `Optional<Brand>` and will return an empty optional when nothing is found you can then do something like this `repository.findByBrandName().orElseThrow(() -> new NoRecordFoundException());` that way you can omit the exists method and do everything in a nice flow.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare in repository (without @Query annotation):

```java
Optional<Brand> findByBrandName(String brandName);
```

And now you can simplify service's code:

```java
@Override
public Brand getBrandByName(String brandName) {
    return brandRepository.findByBrandName(brandName).orElseThrow(() -> new RecordNotFoundException());
}
```

Under the hood Spring Data automaticaly generates SQL according to method name and parameters. To learn more, check out this [article](https://baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries).

In addition, this approach allows to perform only one query instead of two.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting an error `Error creating bean with name 'brandController'`

Comment: @MarijnPloeg I'm sorry, I copied your code and I made a typo :) I have already updated my answer. Method name in repository should be: 'findByBrandName'. Under the hood Spring Data automaticaly generates SQL according to method name and parameters. To learn more, check out this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries